# Performing an assertion in a test written with pytest that should not have occurred

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pytest

Below is the full test code where each assertion is executed. This is unintuitive for me for one reason. If the value of the variable k is None then the function t throws an exception, and thus the code after calling t should not be executed and the exception should be caught by the context manager. However, this does not happen and I do not know why. Not that it bothers me, it's even fantastic that it executes this way, but I'd like to know why.

```py
from contextlib import nullcontext as does_not_raise

import pytest


def t(k):
    if k:
        return k
    else:
        raise ValueError("Value")


@pytest.mark.parametrize("k, cntxt", [(None, pytest.raises(ValueError)), ("Value", does_not_raise())])
def test_t(k, cntxt):
    with cntxt as ex:
        kk = t(k)

        if k:
            assert kk == k
            assert ex is None
        else:
            assert kk is None
            assert str(ex.value) == "Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the value of the variable k is None then the function t throws an exception, and thus the code after calling t should not be executed and the exception should be caught by the context manager.

Unless I have misunderstood you, I believe this is exactly what is happening. In the case when `k` is `None` then these lines aren't executed:

```py
            assert kk is None
            assert str(ex.value) == "Value"
```

To be sure that is the case, you can change the test function to:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("k, cntxt", [(None, pytest.raises(ValueError)), ("Value", does_not_raise())])
def test_t(k, cntxt):
    with cntxt as ex:
        kk = t(k)

        if k is None:
            assert False
```

and it won't fail.

You may want to move the assertions outside of the context manager like so

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("k, cntxt", [(None, pytest.raises(ValueError)), ("Value", does_not_raise())])
def test_t(k, cntxt):
    with cntxt as ex:
        kk = t(k)

    if k:
        print("one")
        assert kk == k
        assert ex is None
    else:
        print("two")
        # Can't do this as kk was never assigned to anything
        # assert kk is None
        assert str(ex.value) == "Value"
```

```bash
$ pytest -s myfile.py
...
two
.
one
.
...
```

Comment: In your variant (with the context manager calling only the function) everything is obvious. But why, in the case I presented, when an exception is thrown is the code following the function call run? If function t throws an exception, that exception is caught by the context manager, so the code after function t is called should never be run.

Comment: It is never run. That is my point. I'm not sure what makes you think that the code following the function runs but it does not.

Comment: Can you check it in PyCharm? I can set breakpoint on else and step into body. Is it PyCharm problem or what?

Answer (score 0):

When `k=None` in your example, the code after `kk = t(k)` is not executed.

However, because everything is inside a `with` block, which is essentially a convenience syntax for try-except-finally, the code execution continues after the block, assert statements are not executed and your test is marked as passed while it should have failed.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

You should put the `assert` statements outside the `with` block